# Google Datastore - Storing dates as ISO 8601 Strings vs java.util.Date

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jodatime, objectify, iso8601

I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and I have noticed that DateTime is stored as a `java.util.Date` in the Google App Engine Datastore for Java, while LocalDateTime is stored as a ISO 8601 compliant String.

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/joda/?r=2d48a85eae3a679c0dc0d01631de99f3b4775b29

I know that `java.util.Date` is a native type of the Datastore.

Is there any particular advantages is storing date/times as a `java.util.Date` as compared to a ISO 8601 compliant String or is it all the same. When I say advantage I might consider differences in regards to ...

- Inequality queries
- Storage size
- Read/write cost
- etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is not wrong, but I would like to add extra details which give a more balanced view.

a) **Stable queries**: ISO-8601 is stable as long as you assert that

- you only use one date format for storage (ISO defines three: calendar date, ordinal date and week date)
- and that you always use one precision degree for the time part (for example always in milliseconds)
- and that you always use UTC with respect to global timestamps (that is zero offset with symbol Z).

Confirming this kind of stability can be application-dependent while `java.util.Date` does not require the same care.

b) **Precision**: ISO-8601 can express more precision beyond milliseconds while `java.util.Date` and Joda-Time are limited here. This is particularly true if you might later think of other new time libraries like JSR-310 in Java 8 or my own one which provide nanosecond precision. Then you will have precision issues with all JDBC types, `java.util.Date` and the database columns as far as they are not CHAR or VARCHAR.

A striking example is the JDBC-type `java.sql.Time` whose precision is limited to seconds, not better. This is pretty much in contrast to the new Java8-type `java.time.LocalTime` which offers nanoseconds. And worse: This aspect is also relevant for Joda-Time and `java.util.Date` in your application layer.

For rather academic purposes: Leapseconds can only be stored in ISO-8601-format, not with `java.util.Date` or similar.

c) **Storage size**: Of course, `java.util.Date` has a more compact representation, but else I have to say that disk space is cheap nowadays, so this is not an item to worry about so much.

d) **Read-Write-costs**: This item is in favor of compact data types like `java.util.Date`. But you have also to consider that even in this case you have to represent it in a human-readable format in any other layer sooner or later (most in logging or in representation layer). So for data exchange with other proprietary applications which expect `java.util.Date` this *native* type is okay, but for **logging purposes or XML-data exchange** ISO-8601 is probably the better format.

And if you really care so much about performance costs, you might even consider a number type (long - 64 bit) to avoid garbage burdens by unnecessary object creation (in extreme edge cases). Remember: `java.util.Date` is just  a wrapper around a long.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of java.util.Date: Stable queries (both inequality and equality), storage size, and interoperability with other GAE languages that have native date representations.

Comment: What do you mean "stable queries"? With an ISO 8601 string inequality queries should work just fine, right?

Comment: The ISO8601 datetime format encodes a timezone, so several different strings can represent the same instant in time. Millis since epoch (java.util.Date) is unambiguous.